# How to write the sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table i have is:

```
lecturer
  lec_name
  s_code
  lec_pass
  ph_no

proposal_info
  metric,stu_name
  p_title
  u_proposal

apply_supervisor
  metric
  lec1
  lec2
  lec3
```

Now I would like to join this these 3 table tables and display all the data in the table of proposal_info only for that particular lecturer who login.How login. How to write the sql query for it? This is the query that i I have written...

```
select p.metric,p.stu_name,p.p_title,p.u_proposal 
from proposal_info p 
    INNER JOIN apply_supervisor a 
    ON p.metric = a.metric 
        JOIN lecturer s 
        ON a.lec1 = s.s_code 
        or a.lec2 = s.s_code 
        or a.lec3 = s.s_code 
where s.s_code = s_code;
```

Comment: Could you be more clear, what do you mean by"lecturer who login.How login".

Comment: Can you give us sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exctally what you require, but from whatever i understood, i have created this one.

```
select p.metric,p.stu_name,p.p_title,p.u_proposal from proposal_info p INNER JOIN
apply_supervisor a ON p.metric = a.metric where 
lec1 = @s_code or 
lec2 = @s_code or 
lec3 = @s_code
```

Check if this can help you.

Where @s_code is the input parameter that you must replace with value.

Comment: i using phpmyadmin as database. I would like to display a list with the data inside the table of proposal_info. Before that, i have do the jsp coding for student to select 3 supervisor and fill in the proposal info then all of this info will insert into the database.After that, when the lecturer login from the login page they would like to view the list which will display all the info that have inserted in the table of proposal_info.So i just want that particular lecturer who login will only get the data from the table of proposal_info.

Comment: @Dolphin. fine can i know what are storing in session after lecturer has logged in. are you storing the lecturer code of lecurer_name or s_code?

Comment: fine then you dont need to join the third table that is lecturer as s_code is also stored in lec1, lec2 and lec3 in the apply_supervisor. So i have edited the answer please check that

Answer (score 0):

```
Select P.metric, P.stu_name, P.p_title, P.u_proposal
From proposal_info As P
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From apply_supervisor As A
                Where A.metric = P.metric
                    And (
                        A.lec1 = 'some lecturer code'
                        Or A.lec2 = 'some lecturer code'
                        Or A.lec3 = 'some lecturer code'
                        )
                )
```

In comments, you mentioned that you are using MySQL. Given that MySQL is not great at handling correlated subqueries. However, you can easily rewrite the above query like so:

```
Select P.metric, P.stu_name, P.p_title, P.u_proposal
From proposal_info As P
Where P.metric In   (
                    Select A.metric
                    From apply_supervisor As A
                    Where A.lec1 = 'some lecturer code'
                        Or A.lec2 = 'some lecturer code'
                        Or A.lec3 = 'some lecturer code'
                    )
```

Comment: @Dolphin - I'm not sure what you mean. You haven't mentioned which database product and version but the above query should work in almost all database systems.

Comment: i using phpmyadmin as database. I would like to display a list with the data inside the table of proposal_info. Before that, i have do the jsp coding for student to select 3 supervisor and fill in the proposal info then all of this info will insert into the database.After that, when the lecturer login from the login page they would like to view the list which will display all the info that have inserted in the table of proposal_info.So i just want that particular lecturer who login will only get the data from the table of proposal_info.

Comment: @Dolphin - `So i just want that particular lecturer who login will only get the data from the table of proposal_info` That is what this query will do. `some code` is the code of the lecturer. The results will only be rows from the `proposal_info` table where the lecturer is referenced in one of the three "lec" columns in the `apply_supervisor` table. If this is not what you want, you really need to supply some sample data and expected outputs.

Comment: @Dolphin - Btw, "phpmyadmin" is not a database. It is an application used to manage a MySQL database. MySQL is the actual database product.

Comment: This is what i want but for the lecturer code it will be different base on which lecturer login.So i just put s_code which is same inside the lecturer table?

Comment: @Dolphin - If I understand your question, yes you will repeat the code of the lecturer for each column since presumably you have the information related to lecturers stored in three columns.

Comment: @Dolphin - You haven't told us how logins related to lecturers so we have no way of answering that aspect. Presumably each lecturer as it relates to the tables you have given us has a code that relates to the columns in the "apply_supervisor" table. If that is not the case, then again, we need some more specific DDL statements about the structure of your tables, some sample inputs and expect outputs.

Comment: rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select P.metric, P.stu_name, P.p_title, P.u_proposal
From proposal_info As P
Where P.metric In   (
                    Select A.metric
                    From apply_supervisor As A
                    Where A.lec1 = 's_code'
                        Or A.lec2 = 's_code'
                        Or A.lec3 = 's_code'
                    )");

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /student_list.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
43:     <td width="200" align="center" class="style1"><strong>View Proposal</strong></td>
44:   </tr>
45: <%   stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
46:         rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select P.metric, P.stu_name, P.p_title, P.u_proposal
47: From proposal_info As P
48: Where P.metric In   (
49:                     Select A.metric

Comment: lecturer table :lec_name s_code lec_pass ph_no
  Ali Mamat A0001 a0001    012-4444444

Comment: apply_supervisor table:metric lec1 lec2 lec3
  149277 A0001 A0002 A0004

Comment: prposal_info table:metric stu_name p_title u_proposal
     149277 Nic         PMS [BLOB - 0B]

Comment: The apply_supervisor and proposal_info table data is inserted by student in student page.After that when lecturer login , for example lecturer with s_code A0001 is login i want only that lecturer get the data from the table of proposal_info. Means that the lec1 lec2 and lec3 inside the table apply_supervisor will match with the s_code inside the lecturer table to get the data inside the table of proposal_info.

Comment: @Dolphin - Update your question with sample data and also show us some expected output.